# Android Login to Website - Always returns login page data

Tags: android, post, authentication, httpclient

I have a login form currently taking login parameters and logging into a website using HTTP Post Request. I am unsure of the server type so that could be the problem. Once it takes the login credentials, it coverts the inputstream to a string (all the html) and sets that to a textview. Here's the login:

```
private void postLoginData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("loginurl"); // Changed for question.

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", "username"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", "pass"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String finalres = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        tvStatus.setText(finalres);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

And here's the inputStreamToString()

```
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
        total.append(line); 
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

The problem is that it ALWAYS just returns the HTML for the login page. When a user fails login on the site, it has a little message to indicate so. Even if I add incorrect credentials, it doesn't display anything different. Likewise, if I add the correct login, it still shows me just the login page HTML.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to get the content of the page after getting logged in? Check for the HTTP status if it is 200 or 401. No need to get the data if just wanted to authenticate.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction in terms of checking the HTTP Status? I've been googling a bit and I can't quite find it.

Comment: Write response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); to Logcat.

Comment: Check my ans. sent 8min before.

Answer (score 2):

To check for HTTP status. Do something like this

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
   //Do Something here.. I'm logged in.
} else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    // Do Something here. Access Denied.
} else {
    // IF BOTH CASES not found e.g (unknown host and etc.)
}
```

This will exactly works as you want to check for status. thanks

Comment: It always returns the first result.

Comment: If it comes in first condition, then it means you're successfully logged in. Now, its up to you what you need to do with that authentication.

Comment: The problem is that even if I enter an incorrect login, the same result occurs.

Comment: Server supports BASIC auth? can you show me your login url so I can try url method too?

Comment: Can we move this to chat? I'd prefer not to share URL publicly

Comment: Sure. can you please make a room and add me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9525/discussion-between-mark-lyons-and-hamza-waqas)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805300/using-httpget-returning-complete-html-code). Check it out, there are some solutions, which might work for you in solving it.